# How to block one collider behind another in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to block one collider object behind the other in a 2D Unity game?
I have colliders for enemies walking on screen but if the enemies walk behind barriers (which have their own colliders), the enemy colliders still respond to the player bullets. So basically i just want to expose the enemies only when they are not behind any barriers.
Currently my bullets go through the barriers and detect the enemies.
I have placed enemies and barriers on separate UI panels and layers but that is just distinguishing them visually. From collision point of view how do i make one (barrier) take priority over the other (enemy)?

Comment: Just use an if statement to destroy (or deactivate if pooling) the object if it hits a barrier, before checking if its an enemy. ---In your collision function, you could say if(collider.gameObejct.tag == "Barrier") {//Destroy object} else if(collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {//Damage enemy }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Raycast methods. You can cast a ray from the player position to the enemy position, if it detects a wall in the middle you don't allow them to shoot.

```
public LayerMask wallsLayer;

bool HasPathFreeOfWalls(Transform player, Transform enemy, float reticleRadius)
{
  Vector2 direction = enemy.position - player.position;
  Vector2 origin = player.position + (direction.normalized) * reticleRadius;
  float distance = direction.magnitude - reticleRadius;

  RaycastHit2D rayHit = Physics2D.Raycast( origin , direction, distance, wallsLayer);

  return rayHit.transform == null; // if does not hit anything, it means that the path is free of walls
}
```

---

Edit to match game description

One way of doing this is offsetting all the colliders to be above the pivot points of their respectivelly gameObjects, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k60Xc.png).

Then you cast a CircleCast around the reticle to detect all objects there and checks which one has the lowest Y position, meaning the one that is in the front. Like this:

```
public LayerMask enemysAndWallsLayers;

bool HasEnemyInFront(Vector2 reticlePosition, float reticleRadius)
{
    RaycastHit2D[] enemysAndWallsHitted; // holds the results of the circle cast
    ContactFilter2D collisionFilter = new ContactFilter2D(); // filter user by the circleCast
    collisionFilter.layerMask = enemysAndWallsLayers;
    collisionFilter.useLayerMask = true;

    Physics2D.CircleCast(reticlePosition, reticleRadius, Vector2.zero, collisionFilter, enemysAndWallsHitted, 0);

    GameObject closestGameObject = null;
    float closestY = Mathf.Infinity;

    foreach(RaycastHit2D objHitted in enemysAndWallsHitted)
    {
        if(objHitted.transform.position.y < closestY)
        {
            closestY = objHitted.transform.position.y;
            closestGameObject = objHitted.transform?.gameobject;
        }
    }

    return closestGameObject != null && IsGameObjectEnemy(closestGameObject );
}
```

The IsGameObjectEnemy() fuction have to be implemented by you in a way that you can tell if it is an enemy or a wall

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention but I am using a reticle to point towards the enemies. So if i raycast, it will pass through everything in between the player and reticle.

Comment: I think the reticle won't be a problem with you make sure that only the walls are in the wallLayer. Anyway, I modified the code so the raycast starts outside of the reticle

Comment: I need to look for collisions only around the reticle. So, even if the ray passes through a bunch of walls which are not around the reticle, it should not affect the ray. Its a shooter game and the targets are around the gun reticle. So if the reticle points at an enemy and there is a wall in front of the enemy (so here the reticle points at both the wall and the enemy) then the wall should cover the enemy. If a wall is not around the reticle or covering the enemy then it should not affect the ray. I am not sure how your modified code handles this. Please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Supposing that the reticle is a circle around the player, you need to pass the reticle radius as an argument, so the origin point of the raycast can be calculated to be outside of the reticle

Comment: Its a static third person shooter like gunman tales with reticle (cross hair) controlled by player. So the reticle moves everywhere on screen. I position the reticle and shoot. Whatever is beneath the reticle is the target. If I set my origin point of ray near the player it is going to hit everything on the way (between player and reticle)

Comment: Now I understand! I editted my answer to match this description

Comment: I am using OverlapCircle instead of CircleCast and instead of looking for y position i am just manually setting the layermask for the enemy container to be the obstacle container layer. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I commented this, but I thought as it might solve your problem, I would offer it as an answer.

On the function that checks the collisions, place the barrier check before the enemy check. E.g:

```
if(collider.gameObejct.tag == "Barrier") {//Destroy object} 
else if(collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {//Damage enemy}
```

This way it will check if it hits the barrier first. If it hits the barrier, no life will be taken from the enemy.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!